# Заменить значения в столбце по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация, numpy

Есть две колонки `Count` и `Сondition`. Хочу заменять значения в `Сondition` с условием.

В `Сondition` есть значения и 0. Если `Count > Сondition` - заменяем 0 ниже на значение, которое было до этого, если оно не 0. `Count < Сondition` - останавливаемся заменять 0 на значение. Второе условие - если `Count < Сondition` не достигнуто, но мы сталкиваемся с другим значением - останавливаем замену по этому значению и следовательно начинаем с другого.

Сделал через `df.loc[(df['Сondition'].shift(1) !=0 ) & (df['Count'] > df['Сondition']), 'Сondition'] = df['Сondition'].shift(1)`, но это работает только построчно, не за раз.

Более [полные данные](http://file.sampo.ru/kv949z/).

Вот пример, что есть:

```
    Count   Сondition
1   27.39   0
2   27.32   0
3   27.33   0
4   27.32   0
5   27.35   0
6   27.35   0
7   27.3    27.16
8   27.24   0
9   27.22   0
10  27.21   0
11  27.17   0
12  27.19   27.15
13  27.21   0
14  27.18   0
15  27.16   0
16  27.17   0
17  27.17   0
18  27.17   0
19  27.18   0
20  27.11   0
21  27.11   0
22  27.11   0
23  27.11   0
24  27.09   0
25  27.12   0
26  27.15   0
27  27.11   27.05
28  27.12   0
```

И как должно получится:

```
Count   Сondition
27.39   0
27.32   0
27.33   0
27.32   0
27.35   0
27.35   0
27.3    27.16
27.24   27.16
27.22   27.16
27.21   27.16
27.17   27.16
27.19   27.15
27.21   27.15
27.18   27.15
27.16   27.15
27.17   27.15
27.17   27.15
27.17   27.15
27.18   27.15
27.11   0
27.11   0
27.11   0
27.11   0
27.09   0
27.12   0
27.15   0
27.11   27.05
27.12   27.05
```

Comment: Не стоит повторять одни и те же вопросы. Для начала в первом своем вопросе покажите свой код, чего вы добились,и с чем конкретно возникли трудности. Повторные вопросы будут закрываться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена значений датафрейма удовлетворяющих условию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144554/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
count, cond = df["Count"], df["Сondition"]

mask = ~((cond.replace(0, np.nan).ffill() >= count) & cond.eq(0))

df.loc[mask, "Сondition"] = df.loc[mask, "Сondition"].replace(0, np.nan)

df["Сondition"] = df["Сondition"].ffill().fillna(0)
```

---

результат:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
    Count  Сondition
1   27.39       0.00
2   27.32       0.00
3   27.33       0.00
4   27.32       0.00
5   27.35       0.00
6   27.35       0.00
7   27.30      27.16
8   27.24      27.16
9   27.22      27.16
10  27.21      27.16
11  27.17      27.16
12  27.19      27.15
13  27.21      27.15
14  27.18      27.15
15  27.16      27.15
16  27.17      27.15
17  27.17      27.15
18  27.17      27.15
19  27.18      27.15
20  27.11       0.00
21  27.11       0.00
22  27.11       0.00
23  27.11       0.00
24  27.09       0.00
25  27.12       0.00
26  27.15       0.00
27  27.11      27.05
28  27.12      27.05
```

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, просто открыть новый вопрос. Подписывать персонально для меня не нужно)